# How to match and find between an array and documents in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of IDs like for example

[id1,id2,id3,......]

and i have a collection with documents for example

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1111111111111"),
    "phoneNumber" : "1234567891",
    "fid" : "id1",
    "pid" : "abcd",
    "activeFlag" : true
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("2222222222"),
    "phoneNumber" : "1234567891",
    "fid" : "id1",
    "pid" : "efgh",
    "activeFlag" : true
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("33333333333"),
    "phoneNumber" : "1234567891",
    "fid" : "id2",
    "pid" : "xyz",
    "activeFlag" : true
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4444444444444"),
    "phoneNumber" : "1234567891",
    "fid" : "id3",
    "pid" : "mnop",
    "activeFlag" : true
}
```

i want to find the documents with fid which match IDs in my array of IDs ,
also i want to sort it according to _id and limit is 9.

if id1 taken then i need all documents which is having fid as id1, like that.

Comment: What have you done so far? Any effort to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should do the trick

```
var listId = ["id1", "id2", "id3"]; 

var cursor =  db.collection.find({fid: {$in: listId}}).sort({_id: 1}).limit(9); 


// iterate over documents
if (cursor != null && cursor.hasNext()){
  while (cursor.hasNext()){
   // print documents
   print(JSON.stringify(cursor.next())); 
  }
}
```

to run it, create a file names `script.js`, copy the code above inside it and then run the command

```
mongo databaseName < script.js
```

Comment: How can i use it for _id field of my documents?   I tried,                           {_id:{$in: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(listId)}

Comment: @Sabreena just put ObjectId in your listId:   `var listId = [ObjectId("12454545"), ObjectId("54575755454"), ObjectId("4545544545")];`